# Question about dense subset of an Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, baire-category

Let $E$ be an Banach space and $A \subset E$ an dense subset. It is possible to find a function $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, for each $x \in A$, $\lim_{t \to x} |f(t)|=\infty$?

I don't know how to start to solve the problem, any tips on how to start will be very helpful.

The only thing that i've notice is that it's possible to find $x_0 \in E$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x_0,\varepsilon) \subset A'$ where $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$.

Comment: As a start, did you try $E=\mathbb{R}$? Regardless of what the answer is, figuring out this will build you intuition!

Comment: Thank you, I will think in the special case of $E=\mathbb{R}$, hopefully I will comeup with a answer and solve my own question :)

Comment: So, I'm thinking the following situation: It's possible to find $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ $\lim_{t \to x} |f(t)|=\infty?$ What is making the problem difficulty for me is that I don't have any additional hypothesis on the function $f$, so $f$ is not necesseraly continuous or linear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use this version of the Baire Category Theorem:

**Baire Category Thereom** :Let $(M,d)$ an complete metric space and $(F_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ an sequence of closed subsets of $M$ such that $M=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$. Then, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_{n_0}$ has non-empty interior.

**My solution**: Suppose by contradiction that for each $x \in A$ we have $\lim_{t \to x} |f(t)|=\infty$ and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ consider the set
$$A_n=\{ x \in E: \text{there exists}\,\, a \in A\,\, \text{and}\,\,\delta>0\,\,\text{such that}\,\,0<||x-a ||<\delta\,\,\text{and}\,\,0<||y-a||<\delta \implies |f(y)|\geq n \}.$$

That is, $A_n$ is the set of points $x \in E$ such that there exists $a \in A$ and a ball $ B(a,\delta)$ such that :$ y \in B(a,\delta) \setminus \{a\} \implies |f(y)|\geq n$ and $x \in B(a,\delta) \setminus \{a\}.$

We have that:

1. $A_n$ is open for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $A_n$ is dense in $E$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

The property $(1)$ is clear. To prove the density property, let $x \in E$ and $\varepsilon>0$. By the density of $A$ in $E$ we know that there exists an $a \in A$ such that $||x-a||<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. We know that there exists $0<\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ such that $y \in B(a,\delta) \setminus \{a\} \implies |f(y)|\geq n$. Then, for an arbitrary $y_0 \in  B(a,\delta) \setminus \{a\}$ it follows that $y_0 \in A_n$ and:
$$||y_0-x||\leq||y_0-a||+||x-a||<\varepsilon. $$

By fact that each $A_n$ is dense in $E$, it follows that for each $n$, $\text{int}(A_n^c)=\emptyset$ and noticing that  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\emptyset$ we have
$$ E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n^c$$
where $E$ is complete, each $A_n^c$ is closed and each $A_n^c$ has empty interior, a contradiction to the Baire category Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

For an example, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$ alike), let $\{r_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable dense subset. Let $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $$\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \infty,\hspace{20mm}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g(x)|^2\ dx =1.$$ For instance $$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} k|x|^{-1/8} &: |x|\leq 1 \\ 0 &: |x|>1 \end{array}\right.$$ for a suitable chosen $k>0$ satisfies the requirement. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}g(x-r_n).$$ The series converges in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so $f$ is well-defined. Clearly $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to r_n}f(x) = \infty$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If your example really works then my proof must have some flaw, do you checked all the details in the calculations of your example?